# Custom ArrayAdapter display the last Information only

Tags: java, android, list, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter` which lists user's data, but it lists the last user's data, it show the correct number of row, if there are 5 users it shows 5 rows but all of them are the same, the last user.

The main activity is this:

```
for(DataSnapshot Ds : dS.getChildren()) {
Object key = Ds.getKey();
String StringKey = String.valueOf(key);
getname(StringKey);
}



private void getname(String ID){

    final String IDfinal = ID;
    DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Name = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(IDfinal).child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Email = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(IDfinal).child("email").getValue(String.class);
            Gender = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(IDfinal).child("gender").getValue(String.class);
            Birthday = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(IDfinal).child("data_birth").getValue(String.class);
            UserInformation ID = new UserInformation(Name,Email,Gender,Birthday);
            userInformationsList.add(ID);
            list();
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,Name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Error 404",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

 private void list(){
     customAdapter customAdapterIntent= new customAdapter(this,R.layout.userslist,userInformationsList);
     mListView.setAdapter(customAdapterIntent);
}
}
```

UserInformation.java

```
    public class UserInformation {
        private static String Name;
        private static String Gender;
        private static String Email;
        private static String Birthday;

        public UserInformation(String Name,String Gender,String Email,String Birthday){
            this.Birthday=Birthday;
            this.Email=Email;
            this.Gender=Gender;
            this.Name=Name;
        }

        public static String getName(){return Name;}
        public static String getEmail(){return Email;}
        public static String getGender(){return Gender;}
        public static String getBirthday(){return Birthday;}


}
```

customAdapter.java

```
public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserInformation> {




  public customAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<UserInformation> userInformationsList) {
    super(context, layoutResource, userInformationsList);

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.userslist, null);
    }

    UserInformation userInformation = getItem(position);

    if (userInformation != null) {
        TextView Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textNameList);
        //name.setText(name[position]);
        TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textEmailList);
        //email.setText(Email[position]);
        TextView gender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textGenderList);
        //gender.setText(Gender[position]);
        TextView birthday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textBirthdayList);
        //birthday.setText(Birthday[position]);

        if (Name != null) {
            Name.setText(UserInformation.getName());
        }
        if (email != null) {
            email.setText(UserInformation.getEmail());
        }
        if (gender != null) {
            gender.setText(UserInformation.getGender());
        }
        if (birthday != null) {
            birthday.setText(UserInformation.getBirthday());
        }
    }

    return view;
}
}
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: you are adding your data in listview using the wrong approach. You position to set data in your list then it will work fine.

Comment: Did you implement the method `getItem()`? If so could you post it?

Comment: @Umair I don't understand what you mean, Shall I put the `setAdapter()` in the `onDataChange` void?

Comment: @gil.fernandes No I haven´t What is the `getItem`for? where shall i put it?

Comment: @EnriqueRamosMuñoz no no. I meant to say you are not setting the data correctly in your list.

Comment: @EnriqueRamosMuñoz not import what I asked. The problem are probably the static modifiers in class `UserInformation`.

Comment: @gil.fernandes the problem was that, thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting values why are you using Class (UserInformation) instead of Class name use its object userInformation.

```
if (Name != null) {
        Name.setText(userInformation.getName());
    }
    if (email != null) {
        email.setText(userInformation.getEmail());
    }
    if (gender != null) {
        gender.setText(userInformation.getGender());
    }
    if (birthday != null) {
        birthday.setText(userInformation.getBirthday());
    }
```

One more thing , make below values non-static

```
  public class UserInformation {
    private String Name;
    private String Gender;
    private String Email;
    private String Birthday;

    public UserInformation(String Name,String Gender,String Email,String Birthday){
        this.Birthday=Birthday;
        this.Email=Email;
        this.Gender=Gender;
        this.Name=Name;
    }

    public String getName(){return Name;}
    public String getEmail(){return Email;}
    public String getGender(){return Gender;}
    public String getBirthday(){return Birthday;}
```

}